# Mathematics calculus

Tags: calculus

Find all critical values for the function
$$f(x) = \frac{5 x + 10}{x^2 + x + 1}$$
and then list them (separated by commas) in the box below.
List of critical numbers:

Comment: It is customary here for the asker to give his own ideas and attempts.

Comment: the denominator is never $0$ (for Real numbers), the nominator is $0$ only when $x=-2$, where are you stuck at ?